# How do I create a Draft.js editor with content from a rest API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, draftjs

I'm trying to create a text editor using Draft.js, and I want it to be initiated with some content. The content is coming from a rest API that I have also created, but I am having some trouble with getting it to work. The editor itself works fine, but when I try to initiate it with the content it no longer works.

The way I'm trying to achieve this is by creating the `editorState` with `createWithContent()`, but I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined.

I believe that it might be that the function that's using the 'getSelection' function is trying to access the `editorState` before its created, however, I'm not sure how to fix it.

This is my editor Class:

```
import React, {useState, Component} from 'react';
import {Editor, EditorState, RichUtils, ContentState, convertFromHTML} from 'draft-js';
import axios from "axios";

class MyEditor extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/BackendWiki/api/brands/Rolex`)
            .then(res => {
                    const brand = res.data;
                    console.log(res.data)
                    if (brand) {
                        const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(brand.description);
                        const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
                            blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
                            blocksFromHTML.entityMap,
                        );
                        this.setState({editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(state)})
                    } else {
                        this.setState({editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()});

                    }
                }
            )
    }


    handleKeyCommand(command, editorState) {
        const newState = RichUtils.handleKeyCommand(editorState, command);

        if (newState) {
            this.onChange(newState);
            return 'handled';
        }

        return 'not-handled';
    }

    _onBoldClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, 'BOLD'));
    }

    _isActive(style) {
        const currentFocus = this.state.editorState.getSelection().getFocusKey()
        //currentStyle is a map of currently applied style to selected text
        const currentStyle = this.state.editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle(currentFocus);
        //check if current style is among the style map.
        return currentStyle.has(style);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button
                    className={this._isActive("BOLD") ? "bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded" : 'bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded'}
                    onMouseDown={this._onBoldClick.bind(this)}
                    isActive={"BOLD"}>Bold
                </button>
                <Editor
                    editorState={this.state.editorState}
                    handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MyEditor;
```

And this is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined
    at MyEditor._isActive (editor.js:52)
    at MyEditor.render (editor.js:63)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17160)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17110)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18620)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21188)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:24373)
    at react-dom.development.js:24758
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21903)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24757)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24840)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (tailwind.output.css?5033:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
_isActive @ editor.js:52
render @ editor.js:63
finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17160
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17110
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:18620
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:292
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23203
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22154
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22130
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:21756
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21188
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24373
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:24758
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:21903
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24757
render @ react-dom.development.js:24840
./src/index.js @ index.js:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:784
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ tailwind.output.css?5033:45
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:784
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <MyEditor> component:
    in MyEditor (at Brand.js:41)
    in div (at Brand.js:36)
    in Brand (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:16)
    in div (at App.js:13)
    in App (at src/index.js:14)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:13)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:19527
logError @ react-dom.development.js:19564
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:20708
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:12490
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12511
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:19883
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:22803
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:292
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:22541
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11039
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22381
finishSyncRender @ react-dom.development.js:21807
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:21793
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21188
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24373
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:24758
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:21903
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24757
render @ react-dom.development.js:24840
./src/index.js @ index.js:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:784
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ tailwind.output.css?5033:45
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:784
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
react-dom.development.js:22665 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined
    at MyEditor._isActive (editor.js:52)
    at MyEditor.render (editor.js:63)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17160)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17110)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18620)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21188)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:24373)
    at react-dom.development.js:24758
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21903)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24757)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24840)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (tailwind.output.css?5033:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Am I missing something or is there a better way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this is based on your stack trace the `_isActive()` function is called which calls `this.state.editorState.getSelection()` once `this.state.editorState` is still `undefined`.

I would add a `null` or `undefined` check in your render for `this.state.editorState`.

```
render() {
   return this.state.editorState ?
       <div>
           <button className={this._isActive("BOLD") ? "bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded" : 'bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded'}
                   onMouseDown={this._onBoldClick.bind(this)}
                   isActive={"BOLD"}>Bold
           </button>
           <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState}
                   handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
                   onChange={this.onChange} />
       </div> : null
}
```

Additionally you can add some kind of loading component instead of `null` in the ternary operator which looks more better until the API call is still in progress like:

```
this.state.editorState ?
     <div> {/* your editor */} </div> :
     <span>Loading...</span>
```

Comment: Holy shit it worked! I've been trying to solve this all day, thanks!